# Jquery Sortable on drag element

Tags: jquery, overflow, jquery-ui-sortable, drag, drop

I am using jquery-ui sortable to drag an element in multiple droppable zones.

I have multiple dropzone on div .left and I need to use overflow-y, but when I drag element from left div to right div, the element goes behind the right div.

[image: This is my problem]

```js
$('.dropzone').sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        connectWith: '.dropzone',
        placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder draggable',
        cancel: ":input, button, .disable-sort-item",
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 10,
        scrollSpeed: 10,
        appendTo:"body",
        zIndex: 99999,
        start: function (event, ui) {
        },
        update: function( event, ui ) {         
        },
        receive: function( event, ui ) {         
        },
        sort: function(event, ui) {    
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {       
        },
        beforeStop: function(ev, ui) {

        },
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="left-panel" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;">
       <div class="dropzone" id="d1" style="">
          <div class= "draggable ui-sortable-handle">Elem Drag</div>
       </div>
       <div class="dropzone" id="d2" style=""></div>
       <div class="dropzone" id="d3" style=""></div>
       <div class="dropzone" id="d4" style=""></div>
    </div>


    <div class="right-panel" style="overflow:hidden;">
       <div class="dropzone" id="d5" style=""></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad english. ;)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Can you update your snippet to reflect the image or provide a jsfiddle link?

Comment: I solved it by myself. Thanks ;)